# How to load big images faster | next.js

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js

It is a full screen image.

1. I use Image component
2. format of the image: wepb
3. info about the image in the photo below

What I tried:

1. used priority={true} [next.js **priority** in image component](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#priority)
2. tried to compress image, its size, resolution but it still loads slow

   ```
       <Image
          src={"/images/video/bg-image.webp"}
          layout={"fill"}
          objectFit={"cover"}
          alt={"background image"}
        />
   ```

[image]

The first time I go to the page, I have to wait at least 5-10 seconds to load an image after that the image loads fast. How can I increase loading speed of the image?

Comment: Are you testing it on a production build? Also have you installed sharp? Which Next.js version are you using? And how are you serving the images? Are you (or your hosting provider) caching the assets or using a CDN? And, how is your network speed? Is is fast enough to download 2.1MB data withing microseconds? Also, can you attach a link to original image (Don't upload it on SO, Imgur does lossy compression)?

Answer (score 1):

first of all you should import Image from next/image not react, If you are testing it at local pay attention for each refresh page you have a request and it is slow, but in production mode it is different and so fast. If you test it online Next.js catches images and have an lazy loading algorithm for the first loading and slow loading may be related to your infrastructures of the web. Also I recommend you use Next.js 12.